# How to get parent and child categories in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to create a loop that loops through all my parent categories, echoes a `<header>` containing its name then below that a list containing its child categories. As showed in the image attatched.

As for now all i got is a simple `foreach` that gets the categories. But i need help with outputting it correctly.

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
));

foreach($categories as $category) {
    //the problem starts here.
}
```

[image]

Comment: show the all category data you getting from the database. or show the database structure.

Comment: Added the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list like this, change the code for radio buttons

```
<?php 

                $taxonomyName = "category";
                $parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));   

                foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
                    echo '<div class="single_cat col-md-3">';
                        echo '<h3>'.$pterm->name.'</h3>'; 
                    $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {

                        echo "<ul>";
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>'; 
                        echo "</ul>";

                    }
                      echo '</div>'; 
                }


                 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Not quite right though. It should only echo the parent once, then its child, then next parent and that ones childs. Also i get error on `echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>'; ` saying "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in"

Comment: Try the code, and let me know, you still get the error, I have updated the code

Comment: Trouble with that is that it shows parent categories that have posts but which don't have child categories.  Thus you can have, say, 'Uncategorized' hanging on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `parent` to do the trick.
Try this approach -

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'parent' => 0,
    ));


    foreach($categories as $category) {
        //Echo parent element  
        $child_categories = get_categories( array(
           'orderby' => 'name',
           'order'   => 'ASC',
           'parent' => $category->term_id,
         ));
        // now loop through $child_categories 
    }
```